# Android sqlite query and check performance

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

So I have a list of events that I get and I am trying to check the sqlite database to see if there are any duplicates since I pull data from multiple apis. Sometimes the spellings are off like `N. Western Ave` vs `North Western Ave` and same with the name of the event, so I have put in multiple if statements and search each row independently but it seems that as the list get larger it starts to lag my app. Is there a better way performance wise to do this?

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT_LATLNG));
                String physical_address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT_ADDRESS));
                String venue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT_VENUE_NAME));
                String sort_date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EVENT_DATE_SORT));

                if (sort_date.equals(check_date)){
                    if (venue.toLowerCase().equals(check_venue.toLowerCase()) || location.equals(check_loc)
                    || physical_address.toLowerCase().equals(check_address.toLowerCase())){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do all these staff in background thread and when all check complete then update Uithread

Comment: Why do you load all data then iterate and make if if checks in code??? You should be using SQL to obtain filtered data from the DB, look up `WHERE` keyword and SQL queries. You should offload filtering to DB if possible.

Comment: @AnasMehar I am doing all this in the background, it never updates any UI during this process, that is done at a very different time, which is fine.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I tried to use `String Query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS + " WHERE " + KEY_EVENT_VENUE_NAME + " =?"` example but it kept telling my script it wasn't a duplicate and I would end up with a lot of duplicates so that is why I am asking is there a better way to do this now.